# Issue using imfill command in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, variables, command

Hi I have a binary variable (called 'column' size 733x1) and I am trying to change the 0's in-between where I have 1's to 1's (i.e. 00001110011... to 00001111111...). I have tried using imfill, however have been unable to do so. I have converted it from type logical to uint8 to help but it hasn't worked.

```
column=column*255 % convert to form to work with 'imfill' command
column_fill=uint8(column)
column_fill=imfill(column);
```

However in between 1's within my variables I still have several 0's which I want to get rid of. [Link to data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ib58auz90eg5f5/data.mat?dl=0). Output (from 000..000111000011101... to 000..000111111111111...) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following sample:

```
load data
column=column100*255 % convert to form to work with 'imfill' command

%Create column filled with 255 values.
white_column = ones(size(column))*255;

%Padd column from both sides (create 3 columns image).
im = [white_column, column, white_column];

%Apply imfill on image im
im_fill = imfill(uint8(im)); 

%Extract center column of im_fill.
column_fill = im_fill(:, 2);
```

---

You can also try the following code without using `imfill`:

```
column_fill = column100;
column_fill(find(column100 == 1, 1):find(column100 == 1, 1, 'last')) = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way of changing this for when it finds the last '1' to change all previous '0' values to '1'. For example (000...000100100000 to 000...000111111111). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`imfill`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html) with the `'holes'` option

```
BW2= imfill(BW,'holes')
```

but you should leave your image binary and not multiply with 255.

Comment: I tried this, it didn't work. Please find the dataset attached. https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ib58auz90eg5f5/data.mat?dl=0

Comment: Your variable `column` should be binary. Did you remove the `*255` from `column=column*255`?

Comment: Yes I did, it's not included in the dataset, it was an approach I thought of.